# Django Create Object without Forms from View with Foreign Keys

Tags: django, model, view

I'm trying to create some service endpoints that create objects based off data sent into the URL. Currently, I'm getting errors that are saying that the various items in my model that have foreign keys, that they don't have an instance started. How can I start an instance or get this to work.

```
Model.py

class timeListened(models.Model):
listenedeventid = models.AutoField(db_column='listenedEventID', max_length=10,primary_key=True)
userid = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser,db_column='userID',blank=False,null=False,max_length=255,default=get_current_user,editable=True)
sermonid = models.ForeignKey(Contentdownloadtable,db_column='sermonID',unique=True,verbose_name='Sermon Name')
dateListened = models.DateTimeField(db_column='dateTimeListened',auto_now=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'timeListened'
        verbose_name = 'Viewed Sermon'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Viewed Sermons'
        app_label = 'web'

service.py

def sermonHistoryAdd(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    if request.GET.get("sermonid","") == "":
        results = 'No Sermon ID passed'
    else:
        sermonid = request.GET.get("sermonid","")
        newHistory = timeListened(sermonid=sermonid,dateListened=datetime.datetime.now(),userid=request.user.id)
        newHistory.save()
        results = 'test'
else:
    results = 'Not Logged In.'
return HttpResponse(results)
```

The Error Message I'm getting is:

Cannot assign "1": "timeListened.userid" must be a "AuthUser" instance.
If I take away userid, I get the same thing for sermonid -- saying that it must be a "Contentdownloadtable" instance.

Why won't it let me create objects that have foreign keys.

```
URLS.py:
url(r'^service/sermonhistory/add/', service.sermonHistoryAdd, name='sermonHistoryAdd'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont your try using

```
userId = model.ForeignKey(User, .....)
```

and uses

```
newHistory = timeListened(sermonid=sermonid,dateListened=datetime.datetime.now(),userid=request.user)
newHistory.save()
```

Comment: Same issue. I can take out the userid part of it all together and it does the same thing with the "sermonid" from Contentdownloadtable model.

Comment: @TrentBrown you have to create an instance of that `Countdownloadtable` from the `sermonid = request.GET['sermonid']` and pass the instance to the `timeListened(....., sermomid=sermonidIntace)` also

Comment: I found out how to do it without creating the instance. I'm curious how you would create an instance. I've seen to have done so much in django without ever doing anything with them.

Answer (score 0):

Everything was good except that I don't want to load an instance for the objects that have foreign keys -- I just need to add _id to the foreign key objects.

```
newHistory = timeListened(sermonid_id=sermonid,dateListened=datetime.datetime.now(),username_id=username)
```